# How to order a dictionary by the key alphabetically

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dictionary = {"Charlie": [[7]], "Alex": [[4]], "Brandon": [[8]]}
OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
print(dictionary)
```

Okay I am trying to order my dictionary by the key, in alphabetical order, but the dictionary doesn't change order after the 3rd line of code as seen above.
Can anyone help me with a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort dictionary by key in alphabetical order Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264956/how-to-sort-dictionary-by-key-in-alphabetical-order-python)

Comment: Also duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/python-dictionary-sort-by-key (I actually like the answers better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OrderedDict` is not a function which orders dictionaries.  That is impossible since dictionaries are naturally unordered in Python. Instead, `OrderedDict` is a special kind of dictionary that supports ordered items.

If you want to use an `OrderedDict` in your code, you will need to save it in a variable:

```
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Note however that `dictionary` will still be unordered after this operation; the line above only uses the items in `dictionary` to construct a new `OrderedDict` object.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to assign it back to `dictionary` as it is not in-place

```
dictionary = OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Now your o/p will be as expected

```
OrderedDict([('Alex', [[4]]), ('Brandon', [[8]]), ('Charlie', [[7]])])
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `key` for your `sorted` function :

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items()))
OrderedDict([('Alex', [[4]]), ('Brandon', [[8]]), ('Charlie', [[7]])])
```