# Sort dict alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

My program can output every student's name and their 3 scores from a dict in a file, but I need to  sort the data by alphabetical order. How can I sort the names and scores alphabetically according to the surname?

This is my code so far:
  import pickle

```
def clssa():
    filename="friendlist.data"
    f=open('Class6A.txt','rb')
    storedlist = pickle.load(f)
    for key, value in storedlist.items():
        sorted (key), value in storedlist.items()  
        print (("{} --> {}").format(key, value))
```

Comment: Is the surname the `key`?

Comment: *the methods I have seen all require the name of the dict*: You *have* the name of the dictionary: `storedlist`.

Comment: @Oh right sorry, new to python haha and yes the first name and surname are the key, e.g. SAM WHITE

Comment: Could you show a few lines of the output your program generates so that we can see what the contents of the dictionaries look like? -- ok you answered that

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate question. The problem included to sort the data by the surnames, which is neither addressed in the linked question, nor in most of the answers here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the sorted keyword.

```
for key, value in sorted(storedlist.items()):
    # etc
```

[How to sort dictionary by key in numerical order Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264956/how-to-sort-dictionary-by-key-in-alphabetical-order-python)

https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are not ordered, so you have to sort the keys and then access the dictionary:

```
for key in sorted(storedlist.iterkeys()):
    print (("{} --> {}").format(key, storedlist[key]))
```

Comment: You can keep it simpler with 'for key, value in sorted(storedlist.interitems())'

Comment: As of python 3.6+, dictionaries are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort by the *surname* of the students, you first have to extract that from the *full name* that is used as the dictionary key. The following function should be able to do that:

```
def get_surname(full_name):
    return full_name.split()[-1]
```

Then you can iterate over the dictionary contents like this:

```
for name in sorted(storedlist, key=get_surname):
    print("{} --> {}".format(name, storedlist[name]))
```

---

A few more tips:

1. In your `frq` function you should replace `skip` with `pass`, which is a valid Python statement.
2. Instead of defining several functions (`clssa`, `clssb`, `clssc`) which are identical except for using a different input filename, you can just write a single function which takes the filename as an argument (and give this function a better name):

   ```
   def print_scores(filename):
       f = open(filename, 'rb')
       storedlist = pickle.load(f)
       ...
   ```

   Inside the function `clssq` you would then replace

   ```
   if clss=='a':
       clssa()
   elif clss=='b':
       clssb()
   elif clss=='c':
       clssc()
   ```

   by

   ```
   filename = {'a': 'Class6A.txt',
               'b': 'Class6B.txt',
               'c': 'Class6C.txt'}[clss]
   print_scores(filename)
   ```