# .bisect not finding closest value in dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have created a list:

```
arraynums = [ 0.3888553  0.3898553  0.3908553  0.3918553  0.3928553  0.3938553
  0.3948553  0.3958553  0.3968553  0.3978553  0.3988553]
```

and a dictionary that has been sorted by key values (here's a portion of the dictionary):

```
sd =({'0.3880434': ['GGATCG'], '0.3883449': ['TTCACG'], '0.388449': ['ATGGCG'], '0.3890966': ['ACTCGC'], '0.3893325': ['GTGGAT'], '0.3893478': ['GATACG'], '0.3900749': ['CAGAAG'], '0.3900875': ['CGAGAG'], '0.3900915': ['ATCGGG'], '0.3901032': ['CACCGG'], '0.3901743': ['AAAGAC'], '0.3906361': ['TACGGC'], '0.390682': ['CCATCG'], '0.3909258': ['GGATGA'], '0.3910728': ['AAGATA'], '0.391648': ['GCAACG'], '0.3919125': ['AGGACT', 'GATCGC'], '0.3921844': ['AGAGAA'], '0.3922956': ['CGGGAA'], '0.3927617': ['ATGGAA'], '0.3927763': ['TTGTCG'], '0.3928683': ['ACAGAC'], '0.39309': ['CGCGCT'], '0.3938553': ['AGGACG'], '0.3940998': ['AAGAGC'], '0.3941768': ['GTCGGA'], '0.394966': ['CGTTCC'], '0.395116': ['TGGAAG'], '0.3954179': ['CCGTCC'], '0.3955623': ['AATCGC'], '0.3956923': ['GGACGG']})
```

I have been using this code to find the closest values to the values listed in the above list:

```
for k  in arraynums:
    index = sd.bisect(k)
    key = sd.iloc[index]
    seq = sd[key]
```

However, the key and seq's printed from this portion of the code does not correctly identify the closest values for k. I'm not quite sure what is going wrong. I think it might have to do with the way I created the `arraynums` list. I created the list using this:

```
arraynums = numpy.arange(float(middlevalue) - 0.005, float(middlevalue) + 0.005, 0.001)
```

EDIT:
A note to the dictionary above: some of the values are negative and the output for each key is the same negative value... I've also sorted the dictionary using `SortedDict()`

Comment: dictionaries are not sorted.

Comment: @njzk2 I sorted the dictionary using `SortedDict(d2)`

Comment: Why does sd have '0.3875103' in front? My compiler doesn't run it. A SortedDict is created like this after all: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25988933/2734863

Comment: Are you perhaps giving SortedDict an unsorted dictionary? It looks like you might be doing the "this does NOT work" thing mentioned here: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict

Comment: @DirkHaupt I'm sorry. That was a mistake. I've fixed the dictionary provided.

Comment: @DirkHaupt It's weird because if I just try a value that is not within the list, the `index`, `key`, and `seq` are the correct output. The problem seems to be with the list.

Comment: I think I've made a mistake with how `.bisect` works. I thought it finds the closest value in a dictionary to the inputed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beyond the type mismatch (`sd` keys are str and `arraynums` elements are float), an efficient way can be:

```
keys=list(zip(sd.items())) 
values= array([x[0] for x in sd.values()])
indices=np.searchsorted(sorted(sd.keys()),arraynums)

In [390]: indices
Out[390]: array([ 3,  6, 13, 16, 21, 23, 26, 31, 31, 31, 31], dtype=int64)
```

`indices` says that  arraynums[0] is beetween keys[2] and keys[3] and so on (see [searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)). There is just a problem with last values : it can be avoid by an other choice of bounds. You have just now to compare for the closest and conclude.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. That makes sense :)