# Python JSON only get keys in first level in same order passed from Angular js

Tags: python, angularjs

How can I get keys in the first level in JSON in the same order as it is passed from angular js? Let's say bellow example.

```
my_dict = {
            'key1': {...},
            'key2': {...},
            'key3': {...}
          }
```

Now when I fetch first level keys in python, it is not giving me in the same order as passed. But for some reason, I want to fetch it in the same order as passed.

```
for item in my_dict:
     print item
```

This gives bellow result.

```
key3
key2
key1
```

Q1 - Why python change it's order?

Q2 - For some reason i want it in the same order like `['key1','key2','key3']`. How can I fetch it?

I tried lots of thing on internet but not getting the solution. Downvoters give the reason, so I can improve my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can internal dictionary order change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975722/can-internal-dictionary-order-change)

Answer (score 0):

Because python's dicts are **hashed tables**. The nature of hashed tables is that they do not keep the initial ordering. Check this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/hash_data_structure.htm) to learn more.

In order to keep your dict in certain order consider using [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Example from python docs on this:

```
>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is a key-value map. It does not guarantee [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489071/in-python-when-to-use-a-dictionary-list-or-set). Use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)