# How do I sort a dictionary that holds variables? (Also save to a file)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm creating a script in python that gets the user's name and lap time, it then saves it into a dictionary which then saves it to a file. How do I sort the dictionary so it shows the lowest numbers first and then the four more scores after that?

```
def lap():

    username = str(input("Name: "))
    time = str(input("Lap Time: "))
    lap_det = {}

    lap_det = str([username + " : " + time])

    with open("lap_time.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(lap_det)

    with open("lap_time.txt", "r") as f:
        print(f.readlines())

    user_r = input("Press r to restart >>> ")
    if user_r == "r":
        lap()
    else:
        quit()

lap()
```

Comment: 1. Post code, correctly formatted, **as text**. 2. SO isn't a tutorial service; if your code needs additional functionality, make an effort to implement it.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, and cannot be sorted.

Comment: Just saying, you don't even have a dict in your code, the moment you defined the dict, you override it with a str. Ie. lap_det

Comment: You can't change the structure of a dictionary. Are you asking how to display the contents of a dictionary in a particular order?

Comment: `input` returns `str`, you don't need to convert the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

Python's `dict` is unordered by default. However in Python 3.6, the dictionary currently keeps its insertion order. Anyway, I would recommend using an `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> laps = {'foo': 12, 'bar': 10, 'fizz': 15, 'buzz': 7}
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(laps.items(), key=lambda k: k[1]))
OrderedDict([('buzz', 7), ('bar', 10), ('foo', 12), ('fizz', 15)])
```

There are some other SO answers on this subject, such as this one:

- [How to sort dictionary by key in numerical order Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264956/how-to-sort-dictionary-by-key-in-numerical-order-python)

Answer (score -1):

You can't sort a dictionary.

Though, if you want to get the values of the dictionary in the same order as the keys, you can use:

```
for key in sorted(dic):
    print(dic[key])
```

(Note: this will just print them)

Please note that using `sorted(dic)` *will not* sort the dictionary, but only iterate over its keys (since iterating over a dict `dic` iterates over `dic.keys()`)

Comment: Don't use `sorted(dic.keys())` In Python 2 this is inefficient, since it creates a *new list* of keys each time. In Python 3, it is merely redundant, since it returns a view of the keys. In any event, all you need is `sorted(dic)` to get a list of sorted keys.

Comment: I was assuming he was using Python 3 since as a beginner he has no reason not to. Also, using `sorted(dic)` may have been ambiguous, he could have though that you could sort the dictionary (since I don't think he knows iterating on a `dict` iterates on its keys...)

Comment: Right, *even if you use Python 3, you should not use `dic.keys()` to iterate over keys...*. It is idiomatic to just use `dic` for that purpose. At the very least, it is adding a needless method call.

Comment: Right, and I don't think it is a valid reason. At the very least, it goes against Python idioms.