# dict is not ordering the content

Tags: python, anaconda3

I installed the Anaconda 3 and I have a problem, I have read that dict is ordered automatically by the keys, but this is not happening in my installation

In the book that I am reading there is this example, wrote in a jupyter notebook:

[image]

**this is what supposed to happen**
[image]

I tested on https://colab.research.google.com and I got the output ordered, so is my anaconda installation the problem? is this just a visual representation?

Sorry for my english, thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you read that it sorts keys alphabetically?

Comment: Python 3.7+ dicts are *insertion-ordered*, not sorted.

Comment: Dicts don't sort alphabetically...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort dictionary by key in numerical order Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264956/how-to-sort-dictionary-by-key-in-numerical-order-python)

Comment: dict objects *maintain insertion order*, they don't maintain a *sorted* order.

Comment: @MichaelH: That doesn't sort either.

Comment: @alec it says in the book that I am reading( is in portuguese), the example is written in a jupyter notebook, I tested on https://colab.research.google.com and I got the output ordered

Answer (score 7):

If you want your dictionary to be sorted alphabetically, you can do the following:

```
>>> print(dict(sorted(dic_estados.items())))
{'AM': 'Amazonas', 'BA': 'Bahia', 'MG': 'Minas Gerais', 'PR': 'Parana', 'RN': 'Rio Grande do Norte'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve the desired output:

```
dic_estados = {"PR":"Parana","MG":"Minas Gerais","BA":"Bahia","RN":"Rio Grande do Norte","AM":"Amazonas"}
sorted_dic = {k : v for k, v in sorted(dic_estados.items())}

print(sorted_dic)
#{'AM': 'Amazonas', 'BA': 'Bahia', 'MG': 'Minas Gerais', 'PR': 'Parana', 'RN': 'Rio Grande do Norte'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

as everybody pointed out the dict are not ordered by the keys, the output in the jupyter notebook uses a function called pprint to show ordered by the keys, and for some reason on my installation this pprint is not working. is not an error

Thanks all